# Disconnect User from SignalR Hub when the User Navigates away from the page

Tags: typescript, react-native, asp.net-core, signalr

I have the following SignalRHub

```
 public class EODStatusHub : Hub    {
       
        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            UserHandler.ConnectedIds.Add(Context.ConnectionId);
            return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            UserHandler.ConnectedIds.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);
            return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }
    }

 public static class UserHandler
    {
        public static HashSet<string> ConnectedIds = new HashSet<string>();
    }
```

And i have a background service that fetches data from the API every 5 seconds depending on whether there are clients connected to the Hub

```
public class TimedEODService : BackgroundService
    {
     
        private readonly ILogger<TimedEODService> _logger;
        private readonly IHubContext<EODStatusHub> _eodStatusHubContext;
        private readonly IEODService _eodService;

        public TimedEODService( ILogger<TimedEODService> logger, IHubContext<EODStatusHub> eodStatusHubContext, IEODService eodService)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _eodStatusHubContext = eodStatusHubContext;
            _eodService = eodService;

        }


        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken token)
        {
            await Task.Yield();

            while (token.IsCancellationRequested == false)
            {
                await Task.Delay(5000, token);
                if (UserHandler.ConnectedIds.Count > 0)
                {
                    StatusReport eodStatus = await _eodService.GetEODStatus();
                    _eodStatusHubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("eodReceived",eodStatus);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**UI TypeScript Code for connector**

```
import * as signalR from "@microsoft/signalr";
const URL = "https://localhost:7082/pochub"; //or whatever your backend port is
class Connector {
    private connection: signalR.HubConnection;
    public events: (onMessageReceived: ( message: any) => void) => void;
    static instance: Connector;
    constructor() {
        this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl(URL)
            .withAutomaticReconnect()
            .build();
        this.connection.start().catch(err => document.write(err));
        this.events = (onMessageReceived) => {
            this.connection.on("eodReceived", ( message) => {
                onMessageReceived(message);
            });
        };
    }
    public newMessage = (messages: string) => {
        this.connection.send("newMessage", "foo", messages).then(x => console.log("sent"))
    }
    public static getInstance(): Connector {
        if (!Connector.instance)
            Connector.instance = new Connector();
        return Connector.instance;
    }
}
export default Connector.getInstance;
```

When a User is on the page , i need the connection established and the API call to be made every 5 seconds. This works fine, but the user is not disconnected when he/she leaves the page. The API is being called every 5 seconds irrespective of whether the user is in the page.

**This is how the UI Page looks like**

```
const EODStatus = () => {
     const { newMessage, events } = Connector();
     const [message, setMessage] = useState("initial value");   
     const initialRender = useRef<boolean>(false);    
            useEffect(() => {      
                events((message) => setMessage(message));
            }, []);
           return (
           <>   
    <span>message from signalR: <span style={{ color: "green" }}>{JSON.stringify(message)} 
       </span>
       </>
    }
```

Comment: Not sure about react, but in angular you have lifecycle hooks for when your component gets created/removed - googling brought me to the unmount, maybe you can use that? https://retool.com/blog/the-react-lifecycle-methods-and-hooks-explained

Comment: @sommmen The component is declared as a constant. Do not know if lifecycle hooks will work.

Comment: Maybe the docs on [client disconnection scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#client-disconnection-scenarios) help you.

Comment: You might consider adding a `visibilitychange` event listener to the component's `useEffect` hook.